# Dependency issue in 8.1u3 NuGet package

Tags: nuget

Using a blank .NET 4.5 web project, the Sitecore NuGet package from https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json for 8.1.160519 (u3) fails to install with the error message:

```
Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core' that is
compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors 5.1.2 constraint:
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (>= 5.1.2 && < 5.2.0)'.
```

The issue appears to affect several of the component packages depended on by the 'Sitecore' package.

Has anyone installed the NuGet package for this version successfully, or found a way around this dependency issue?

Comment: seems odd, how did you create your web project? (which template and options) Can you post your current packages config?

Comment: Can you try changing your target from 4.5 to 4.5.2 - it could be that the dependency requires 4.5.2 as 4.5 is no longer supported.

Comment: @RichardSeal That sounds correct. We had a similar thing with one of our solutions, and that fixed it.

Comment: @RichardSeal Convert that comment into an answer. I've had the same issue, and your solution is the right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your build target from `4.5` to `4.5.2` in your project properties.

The MS dependencies will not be compatible with 4.5 since that is now unsupported. So it can't find a dependency that matches your project target and fails.